# Trying to incorporate void functions into switch statements

Tags: c++

I'm a novice coding student and trying to create a menu using structs, functions, and switch statements to make a mini database for a class assignment. I'm trying to implant the functions into the switch statements.

I'm getting errors on lines 87 and 137 and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Any help, explanation, or correction is much appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

//  Jaret Clark
//  Week 3 Interactive Assignment
//  INT 499
//  Prof. Joseph Issa
//  03/31/2022 


struct EZTechMovie {
    string name;
    string *cast[10];
    string rating;
    
};

void displaymovie(EZTechMovie movie, int cast_num) {

    int i;

    cout << endl;
    cout << "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~" << endl;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Your entry:\n";

    //Movies
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Movie TITLE: " << movie.name;
    cout << endl;

    //Movie rating
    cout << "Movie Rating: " << movie.rating;
    cout << endl;

    //Cast name
    cout << "Main Cast Members: \n";

    //loop for cast members ~ stores in array
    for (int i = 0; i < cast_num; ++i) {
        cout << movie.cast[i];
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void mainmenu() {
    string movie_input;
    int m;

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Would you like to store movies into database? (yes or no) ";
    getline(cin, movie_input);
    cout << endl;
    if (movie_input == "yes") {
        string cont;
        string cast_name;
        int x, m, n, i, cast_num;
        EZTechMovie moviedb[100];

        cout << endl;
        cout << "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~" << endl;
        cout << endl;

        for (n = 0; n < 100; n++) {

            cout << "Movie Title: ";
            getline(cin, moviedb[n].name);
            cout << endl;

            cout << "Movie rating: ";
            getline(cin, moviedb[n].rating);
            cout << endl;

            cout << "How many cast do you want to enter? ";
            cin >> cast_num;
            cout << endl;

            cin.ignore();
            for (i = 0; i < cast_num; i++) {

                cout << "Cast name: First and Last name: ";
                getline(cin, moviedb[n].cast[i]);
                cout << endl;

            }
            cout << endl;

            displaymovie(moviedb[n], cast_num);
            cout << endl;

            cout << "Add more movies? (yes or no) ";
            getline(cin, cont);

            if (cont == "no") {
                break;
            }

            cout << endl;
            cout << "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~" << endl;
            cout << endl;
        }

    }
    else if (movie_input == "no") {
        return;
    }
    else {
        cout << "INVALID Input";
        mainmenu();
    }
}



// menu
void movieMenu() {
    int choice;
    EZTechMovie movie;

    do {
    cout << "***********************Welcome to EZTechMovie Movie Entry Menu***********************" << endl;
    cout << "Press 1 to Enter Movie Info - Name, Cast Members, and Rating.\n";
    cout << "Press 2 to Retrieve movie info recently entered.\n";
    cout << "Press 3 To Quit program.\n";

    // evaluate menu options in switch case
    switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            mainmenu();
            break;
        case 2:
            displaymovie(EZTechMovie movie, int cast_num);
            break;
        case 3:
            cout << "Thank you and Goodbye!";
            break;
        default: 
            cout: "Invalid Selection. Try again!\n";
    }

    //get menu selection
    cin >> choice;
    } while (choice != 3);
    


}

int main() {
    movieMenu();
}
```

Comment: Can you please remark lines 87 and 137 by a comment? What errors you get? (Please, copy paste the error messages literally.) Even better would be a [mcve] instead of just a code dump. And, btw. `mainMenu()` calls itself. With a bit luck, the compiler can recognize a tail recursion but nevertheless it's bad design. You should make a loop instead.

Comment: One time you "call" `displaymovie(EZTechMovie movie, int cast_num);` by simply copying it's declaration (can't work) and one time you call it with actual parameters `displaymovie(moviedb[n], cast_num);`.You know how to call the function properly, so what do you assume should the first one do?

Comment: You took a wrong turn when you decided to not store the size of the cast in the movie information, another when you decided that the cast should be an array of pointers.

Comment: BTW: `movieMenu` is actually the main menu, and `mainMenu` only adds movies. Words mean things. Don't confuse yourself by pretending they don't.

Comment: `displaymovie(EZTechMovie movie, int cast_num);` that's not a function call, the type-id is not expected there. Maybe you should read the errors some, not just line numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the error on line 87  (`getline(cin, moviedb[n].cast[i]);`)  :

`moviedb[n].cast[i]` is a `std::string*`, not `std::string` like you might have meant.

A quick compilation fix would be to use:

```
getline(cin, *(moviedb[n].cast[i]));
```

i.e. dereference the pointer.

However - this code raises other design/programming issues:

1. Why do you use `std::string*` and not `std::string` in the first place.
2. Why do you use C style array instead of `std::vector` (or `std::array` if you can commit to the size). This is relevant for both: `string *cast[10];` and `EZTechMovie moviedb[100];`